# Getting localStorage from Ionic application in my React Native app

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, local-storage

We are rebuilding an Ionic 1.x application with React Native. The app is used by a lot of people and I don't want everyone to log in again after they update the app.

The current app uses localStorage to save the token that defines if a user is logged in (I know, it's not the safest method). Is there a possibility that we can get the current token from the localStorage in React Native and put in our secure storage?

So basically can we call the localStorage instance in React Native? We are using the same bundle identifier so many there is a possibility to access the localStorage from the old app.

Comment: i think its not possible. Users have to Sign In again.

Answer (score 0):

You wont treat with a web enviroment like Ionic, then `localStorage` wont exist, but you can use [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) instead in react native or some DB like sqlite, realm, whatermelonDB (the last one I didnt use) to save your user data

Comment: I indeed want to use AsyncStorage but I wan't to copy the storage from the old app in the new Storage system.